# how to store foreign key ids in another table

Tags: asp.net

I have four tables:

```
M_Division

Division_ID(primary key) Division

1 abc

2 xyz
```

---

```
M_Designation

Designation_ID(primary key) Designation

1 scientist

2 doctor
```

---

```
M_emp personal


empid(primary key) Divsion_ID(foreign key) Designation_ID(foreign key) emp_name

1 1 1 mike

2 2 2 justin
```

---

```
M_temp

empid(foreign key) Divsion_ID(foreign key) Designation_ID(foreign key) date purpose

1 1 1 12-06-2013 xyz

2 2 2 12-06-2013 abc
```

I want to Insert the foreign key ID's into the M_temp table... If I give a query like this,it gives me the foreign key constraint error.....

```
Insert into M_temp(EmpID,DivisionID,DesigID,date,purpose,reason,created_date) Select(EmpID,DivisionID,DesigID from M_emp_personal where Empid=@empid",conn);
```

purpose,date are the form fields in my ASP.NET and they need to be inserted in the M_temp along with the DivID DesigID and EmpID...thats the problem I am facing...I don't know how exactly to do this can somebody please help me out?

This is the C# code

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string RelaseDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.ToString();

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into T_TADA_tempform(EmpID,DivisionID,DesigID,date,purpose,reason,created_date) values(@EmpID,@DivisionID,@DesigID,@GPFNo,@date,@purpose,@reason), conn);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", ddlname.SelectedValue);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DivisionID", divisionID);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesigID", lbldiv.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", RelaseDate);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purpose", ddlpurpose.SelectedValue);

       if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       {
           conn.Open();
           int cnt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           conn.Close();
           if (cnt == 1)
           {
               Response.Redirect("");

           }
           else
               Response.Write("Form has not been submitted,Please Try again!");
       }
   }
```

Comment: At the very least, in your query you say that you want to insert 7 fields, but actually insert 3.

Comment: ohh okay...can u let me know how do i do that?...

Answer (score 0):

You can insert only those ids as foreign key in the T_TADA_tempform table which contains its parent tables like M_Division and M_Designation.

Thus, you have to insert the record in the M_Division and M_Designation table first then you can take appropriate DivisionID and DesigID from here to insert in the main table.

So you can show two more dropdownlists on the asp.net form which will bind from M_Division and M_Designation tables.

You also have to add all the values for parameters which are written in the query, So your complete query will be something like this:

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into T_TADA_tempform(EmpID,DivisionID,DesigID,date,purpose,reason,created_date) values(@EmpID,@DivisionID,@DesigID,@GPFNo,@date,@purpose,@reason,@created_date), conn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", ddlname.SelectedValue);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DivisionID", divisionID);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesigID", lbldiv.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", RelaseDate);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purpose", ddlpurpose.SelectedValue);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reason", "Please put appropriate reason here!");
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_date", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: thanx for the reply...its still not working...i want the ids of designation division and empid to be stored in the M_tempform plus the other data in the tempform